# How to get href value inside html object with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i got an object like this

```
 var obj = $("#something");
 alert(obj.html());
```

and inside `obj.html()` I have:

```
 text <a href='link\to\somewhere'> click here </a> text
```

The question is, how do I get the values `link\to\somewhere` and  `click here` by using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var href = obj.find("a").attr("href"), // "link\to\somewhere"
    text = obj.find("a").text();       // "click here"
```

Answer (score 2):

For finding href:

```
var href = obj.find("a").attr("href");
```

This is because href is an attribute of the `<a>` tag and hence the jQuery method `attr()` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

for href :

```
href = obj.find("a").attr("href");
```

and for click here :

```
text = obj.find("a").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on what you already have:

```
var obj = $("#something");
var html = obj.html();
```

You can then pass the html to jQuery if you want to access it:

```
var href = $(html).attr('href')
```